# PHP MSQL mail function auction style

Tags: php, html

Hi i need help im totally stuck, 
i am learning php my teacher want me to code a function
that

has mailing function for auction winner and auction higher bidder tested with auction expire time how do i do that can anyone show me the code?

do i have to pass any into the object or function ?

Comment: This is suppose to be your homework not others homework. I'm your teacher by the way

Answer (score 1):

Please look into the [Manual](http://php.net/mail).

Syntax:

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

Comment: thanks is that just for 1 winner of the auction or the winning bidder or both ?